# Creating a custom rest API in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, custom

I am new in Marketing cloud any help would be appreciated.
I need to create multiple custom APIs with Get and Post.

I have found some documents on using a landing page and a script inside that will act as an API.

My endpoint will receive a date and retrieve all the records that were updated after this date from a data extension.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you try? Where are you stuck?
As you are writing, there are multiple resources online which both [explain the basics of Cloud Page Code Resources](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/config/sfmc-code-resource/), as well as showcase how to [implement custom APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QL6fGGdDc64).

If you are new to developing on SFMC, I will suggest familiarising yourself with both [Ampscript](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/ampscript-for-nondevelopers/get-to-know-ampscript) and [SSJS](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/marketing-cloud-programmatic-languages/learn-about-server-side-javascript) utilising both official resources as Trailhead and documentation, as well as the magnitude of blogs out there. [SFMC Curated](https://sfmc-curated.com/) provides a consolidated overview of latest posts from across all of the most important ones.

Comment: Thank you Lukas for you prompt response and for the content you have shared.
I was following the video about implementing a custom API.
My initial issue was that Lookuprows was not covering my needs and I was trying to find a way to call a query.

I then found WSProxy and retrieve which helped me get the records I required.

As I am coming from a more traditional programming background my fear is not understanding the basics of creating a custom API and ending up with all the wrong practices.

Is the path of the landing page the correct way?

Comment: Yes @Rafael - using Cloud Page Code Resource is indeed the right way forward. You should be using JSON code resource (not a standard landing page), and observe that it is not trivial to include an authentication process in this custom API (e.g. utilising OAuth is not immediately possible)

Comment: Thank you again. Is there a reason using a json code resource and rendering it in a landing page instead of just writing the code in the landing page?
Also thank you for the authentication tip. (I will be checking out the last video of the series you have provided)

Comment: @Rafael You should not render it in a landing page. Just create a Code Resource. It will get it's own URL, and you will be able to call this URL as an API endpoint. Also, using JSON CR will ensure the correct content-type for your response back to the API client.